# loading an external webpage in navigation frame in silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, navigation

**Problem:**
 In my silverlight tool, have a `<Navigation:frame/>` Now want to load Google home page in that frame on click of a button or may be on load..

**What I have Tried:**
Now I have tried having the source of the frame as "http://www.google.com", dint work, says invalid url, I do not have uri mapping though.
And tried on a hyperlink to put `NavigateUri="http://www.google.com"` `TargetName="ContentFrame"` like this still no luck.

**Intention:**
 I actually wanted to get the page content in a XML format or some other format so that I can modify the content of google page through code and then populate in the frame.

Need help here.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using silverlight in the browser, you cannot load a web page 'in context' you have to load it as an external page.

Sort of...

You 'can' load an a page through the webclient, but you may need to set a client access policy to go external.

You can also call a WCF service back end and have that do the 'loading' for you.  Like a your own custom proxy.

If it's XML format, it might be useful to try the webclient with a client access proxy.

OH, and I've remembered, you could setup a div that is not visible until the button is clicked and load the content in that, as silverlight can use javascript to load dynamic html.